# What exactly happens if I choose to erase a game's progress?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza

In `Settings > Other`, I have the option to "Delete [Subgame] Progress" for each subgame. I am considering doing this for Warrior's Way because I've hit max numbers and have all the hat tickets for having said high numbers. I'd like to know exactly what "progress" means before going through with it though, because while I presume that completed tickets will stay completed, I don't want to lose progress for incomplete tickets (such as, I have about 180 wins vs. opposing player-monarchs out of the necessary 300, and I don't want that to restart).